# "Equations of motions" and direction of maximal entropy

Tags: statistical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, entropy, hamiltonian-formalism, equations-of-motion

Say one has a system of statistical physics whose entropy is given as a function of one or multiple variables; for example as $S(x)$. An example of such a system could be a osmosis system, or a polymer in a bath of water.

It seems to me that if $x$ represents a position, then solving $dS(x)/dx=0$ should give an equation of motion, as a system of statistical physics ought to evolve over time in the direction of maximal entropy. Is there a procedure, similar in generality as the Lagrangian or Hamiltonian formalism, that is able to produce equations of motions using entropy $S$, instead of $L$ or $H$ as the starting point?

Is solving $dS(x)/dx=0$ sufficient to get the equation of motion? A bit more is surely required as we haven't referenced time yet. How does the direction of maximal entropy relate to the 'motion' or evolution of a system over time?

Comment: $dS(x)/dx=0$ at most determines stationary points. That is not a differential equation but just an equation.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Looking into it further, I noticed the notion of an entropic force which is defined as the gradient of the entropy. $F(x)=\nabla S(x)$. Would this be an equation of motion, or am I still missing something?